# Microsoft Access WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, vba

Ok, I have a WebBrowser control in Microsoft Access, I want to load a page into the control and fill in textbox values, and return the values of labels as variables.

Before anyone says it, I already have the project done in C#, but the client wants it in Access.

My code to load the webpage is below:

```
Dim strURL As String
Dim objIE As Object

strURL = "https://mywepage.com"
Set objIE = Me.WebBrowser2.Object
objIE.Navigate strURL
```

In C#, I fill in TextBox values with the following code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ITEMID").SetAttribute("value", id);
```

How do I replicate this in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can do it in VBA

```
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim IE As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "https://mywebpage.com"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set objCollection = IE.document.GetElementById("ITEMID")
objCollection(0).Value = "value"
```

A very clear example here: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can access IE's DOM for the page once its loaded;

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
   WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("search").elements("q").Value = "blah"
   WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById(....)
End Sub
```